# Правильная связка MYSQL запроса

Tags: php, mysql

Существует три таблицы.

- Товары
- Пользователи
- Фотографии
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача стоит такая. Необходимо показать списком 10 товаров указать имя человека который добавил этот товар и также показать фотографию этого товара если она есть.

Связь между товаром и пользователем обязательно должна находить друг друга. Если пользователя не существует то товар не выводится. А вот связь между товаром и фотографиями не обязательно. Тоесть если товар существует но фотографии для этого товара нет то все равно выводим этот товар.

Вот что у меня получилось.

```
SELECT A.name, B.name as user_name, C.foto
FROM items A
INNER JOIN users B ON A.user_id = B.id
LEFT JOIN foto C ON A.id = C.item_id
LIMIT 0,10
```

Все работает быстро и примерно даже так как мне необходимо. Проблема заключается в том, что если у товара существует больше чем одна фотография, товар выводится столько раз сколько у него фотографий. Решил использовать

```
GROUP BY A.id
```

После чего в разы увеличилось время на обработку запроса.

Как посоветуете сделать такую связку?

Comment: Если устроит случайное фото, то `LEFT JOIN (SELECT f.foto FROM foto f WHERE A.id = f.item_id LIMIT 1) C`. Если нужно определённое, то в таблице foto следует ввести поле с пометкой основное/дополнительное или принять иные меры снятия неоднозначности.

Comment: А случайное в плане random или последнее добавленное с этим id товара?

Comment: @Akina MySQL разве позволяет в подзапросе в join обращаться к внешне расположенной таблице (т.е. к `A`) ? Эдакий автоматический lateral или apply ...

Comment: @Mike *MySQL разве позволяет в подзапросе в join обращаться к внешне расположенной таблице (т.е. к A) ?* Не-а... это у меня LEFT JOIN скопировался из сообщения...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT A.name
     , B.name as user_name
     , (    SELECT f.foto 
            FROM foto f 
            WHERE A.id = f.item_id 
            /* ORDER BY f.priority */ 
            LIMIT 1
       ) AS foto
FROM items A
INNER JOIN users B ON A.user_id = B.id
LIMIT 0,10;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Все получилось и время запроса стало очень маленьким. Спасибо еще раз!